# Storing an iterator into a string (Conversion, cast, append ?)

Tags: c++, string, iterator

I'm trying to copy a string into another character by character. The aim is not to copy the whole string but only a part of it (I'll do some conditions later for that..)

But I don't know how to do by using `iterators`.

Can you help me ?

```
std::string str = "Hello world";
std::string tmp;

for (std::string::iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it)
    {
        tmp.append(*it); // I'd like to do something like this.
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you use + operator to concatenate to string like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    string str = "Hello world";
    string tmp = "";

    for (string::iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it)
    {
        tmp+=(*it); // I'd like to do something like this.
    }
    cout << tmp;
    getchar();
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I found another way to do it but it was a little more complicated, your solution looks better ;)
I was storing the (*it) in a char and I append the char to the str... Was more complexe than you

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
std::string str = "Hello world";
std::string tmp;

for (std::string::iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it)
{
    tmp += *it; 
}
cout << tmp;
```